# What is "UNIKONG"?

Tags: support, stackexchange

I have just noticed that I am getting adverts for `UNIKONG` on all the SE sites, what is this about? I have a lot of ad and script blockers installed so this can't just be some ordinary advert... It also wasn't here earlier on in the day, is this like the bash hats? Does it come every year or something?

[image: UNIKONG advert on AU]

Comment: Click it, it is a game you can play :)

Comment: look at the calendar...

Comment: ----^ From the Kingdom of the bleedingly obvious...  **;-)**

Comment: @Seth: It wasn't April the 1st yet in my time zone when it first appeared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this year's **Stack Exchange Easter Egg** for **April fools day**.

It's a simple game similar to Donkey Kong, but with an evil unicorn instead of a gorilla - therefore the name **"UniKong"**. Oh, and the character you control depicts the genius universalis of Stack Overflow, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/Jon-Skeet).

To play it, I would recommend you to use a Chrome/Chromium browser, my Firefox made it a bit slow...

P.S. Last year, the Easter Egg was a Tamagochi-like game to build a site and keep it alive.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's the best thing since IPv6. Click it!